# Deleting row that is placed before the row of our matching condition

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please suggest how I can delete the row that is before a specific criteria.
Eg. How can i drop row 'f' which is one row before the row of my condition (Delta < 10)

```
 A   B  DateTime           Direction    Nom   Delta 
a  6.5  1  2017-06-01 15:37     B          10    Na
b  6.8  0  
c  7    0  
f  6    1  16:21                S           6    25   
h  6.1  1  16:28                S           15   7  
i  6.2  0  
j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need compare column and shift mask, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['Delta'].lt(10).shift(-1).fillna(False)]
print (df)
     A    B          DateTime Direction   Nom  Delta
a  6.5  1.0  2017-06-01 15:37         B  10.0    NaN
b  6.8  0.0               NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN
c  7.0  0.0               NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN
h  6.1  1.0             16:28         S  15.0    7.0
i  6.2  0.0               NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN
j  NaN  NaN               NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN
```